# Open terminal, run python script and keep it open for results?

Tags: python, linux, sh, gnome

How to get an sh script for starting a new terminal, execute a python script and keep it running? The python script is supposed to run continuously in a perpetual loop, spitting out results as they pop in. Whenever trying with sh-script for gnome-terminal just getting: child process exited normally with status 2

Manually it would just be: python home/ubuntu/pyscript.py

Could someone give an idea how to do this?

I have a list of scripts to run, so resorting to the manual solution is tedious.

Comment: add `&` at the end of the line e.g `python home/ubuntu/pyscript.py &`, run in background, also you should append output to file for debug and monitoring `python home/ubuntu/pyscript.py >> pyscript.log 2>&1 &`

Comment: Show us your current attempt so we can see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gnome-terminal` with the `-x` flag.
Suppose you have a `spam.py` script; then the following command will spawn a new terminal, run `spam.py` in it, and close the terminal once the script has ended.

```
gnome-terminal -x python spam.py
```

Try with this script:

```
# spam.py
import time

for _ in range(5):
    print("eggs")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Then the previous command will spawn a terminal, that will be printed `eggs` five times, and then will be closed.

If you want to leave the terminal open with the Python interpret still running after the script ended, then Python's `-i` flag ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html) then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> -> `-i`) is what you want:

```
gnome-terminal -x python -i spam.py
```

Answer (score 0):

To run the Python script in a new instance of your favourite terminal, write:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e python -i home/ubuntu/pyscript.py
```

This will start the Python script and run it until it ends, then display a Python prompt to stop the terminal emulator from closing.

This will work with `x-terminal-emulator` substituted with any of the many, many terminals installed on my computer, so will work with little modification across all POSIX-compatible systems with the standard terminals installed. This won't work on a Mac, however. For a *properly* cross-platform Python implementation of something slightly different, see [here](https://github.com/PolyEdge/ScratchEdit/blob/b8270e7e01202210400b5f1b7a3347efc4e6a2b3/ScratchEdit.pyw#L193-L240). Most of the techniques should be transferable.

---

To run the Python script in the same terminal whilst carrying on with the rest of the shell script, write:

```
python home/ubuntu/pyscript.py &
```

Note the `&`, which runs the program as a new process (but still connects the output to the virtual terminal).